# "Nobody's here" vs "people aren't here"

Tags: difference, phrases

"Nobody's here" vs "people aren't here"

What's the difference?

I think in the former, there are no people, but in the latter, there are people but they are not here.

Comment: "People aren't here" isn't idiomatic. You might say "The students aren't here" or "The team isn't here" but normally only with reference to a particular group of people. Or "There are no people here" would also be fine. I'm not sure if you mean to refer to a specific group of people or all the world's population.

Comment: @StuartF I mean "any person isn't here".

Comment: It's weird, I have a strong feeling of deja vu as if this exact question was asked in the past few weeks, but I can't find it...

Comment: People aren't here. is fine even though it is often accompanied by yet.

Comment: _People aren't here_ makes sense only in the context that there is a specific group or constituency of people expected, so it means "(None of) the people I would expect to be here are here".

Answer (score 0):

"People aren't here" sounds really odd to me. You might want to add "the" before "people". I'd say something like:

1. There are no people here
2. There's nobody here
3. Nobody's here yet
4. The people aren't here yet. (This implies, we are waiting for somebody, who hasn't arrived yet)
5. This place is empty.

Comment: Actually, you don't necessarily need the the for the people aren't here.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Dmytro that on its own, People aren't here sounds odd, but I can think of some examples where either phrase would sound fine in context, but would change the meaning of the sentence.

For example. Suppose my friend is about to go on stage to perform a comedy routine, and I say to him: "There's nobody here to watch you do standup". This would mean that there is literally no one in the audience to see him perform his routine. Alternatively, if I say, "Nobody's here to watch you do standup" this would probably mean that there are people in the audience, but they are there for a reason other than watching the standup act.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, here's the difference between the two:

> You **wouldn't** say *People aren't here*.
>
> You **would** say ***Nobody's here.***